# Fetch data with Hibernate Query Language and 'like'

Tags: java, hibernate, primefaces

I am using primefaces `<p:autoComplete completeMethod="#{bean.autoComplete}">`. 
In my `autoComplete(String query)` method , I need to fetch the `names` starting with `query`.How can I do it with `hibernate like`.Where `query` is what I enters in to the text field.

I am using JSF2 with Primefaces-3

Comment: What did you try so far? I don't see any real primefaces specific in your question, it's more like "how do I use Hibernate", right?

Comment: yes, I just need the hibernate query for fetch the `names` with `like`. I included `primefaces` just to specify the `query` is what I enter in the `text box`.

Comment: RTFM: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#queryhql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Hibernate criteria:

```
List names = session.createCriteria(TableName.class).add( Restrictions.like("name", query+"%") ).list();
```

Look [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html) for details.